# What is the best procedure to detrend data without loosing its anisotropy?

Tags: spatial, trend, geostatistics

I wand to detrend some spatial data "A" with respect to two parameter "B&C". What is the best procedure to detrend A without loosing its anisotropy. Theoretically values of  "A" should be anisotropic and has no trend with respect to "B" & "C". The real measured value of "A" show some trend with respect to "B" & "C". By using the classical method of detrending, the data loos their properties of anisotropy and become isotropic. 
Dose anyone know a  procedure to detrend data without loosing its anisotropy?

Answer (score 1):

The concepts of anisotropy and trend are disconnected. If you remove a trend and the residual map does not show preferential directions of spatial continuity, then use a isotropic model.

You could question, however; if there is indeed a trend in your application. In many cases what you see is just a result of random fluctuation, specially if you have a process with large range. The random function can have zero mean everywhere and by just looking at a single realization, you cannot tell.